# Running a Zimbra image in Docker failure

Tags: ubuntu, docker, zimbra

I'm trying to start up Zimbra using docker, however I seem to keep running into issues when starting the container after pulling it.

I use the following command to start the container:

```
docker run -p 35:25 -p 8021:80 -p 465:465 -p 587:587 -p 110:110 -p 143:143 -p 993:993 -p 995:995 -p 7443:443 -p 8082:8080 -p 8443:8443 -p 7071:7071 -p 9071:9071 -h webmail.[hidden].com--dns 8.8.8.8 -i -t -e PASSWORD=[hidden] jorgedlcruz/zimbra
```

The port configuration is due to other installations running on the machine, but I seem unable to even start it.
The following output is given upon using above command:

```
Configuring DNS Server
 * Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server configuration syntax check                                                                                                                                                                                  [fail] 
Downloading Zimbra Collaboration 8.7.11
--2018-04-12 21:25:23--  https://files.zimbra.com/downloads/8.7.11_GA/zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956.tgz
Resolving files.zimbra.com (files.zimbra.com)... 54.192.198.49
Connecting to files.zimbra.com (files.zimbra.com)|54.192.198.49|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 267603851 (255M) [binary/octet-stream]
Saving to: '/opt/zimbra-install/zimbra-zcs-8.7.11.tar.gz'

/opt/zimbra-install/zimbra-zcs-8.7.11.tar.gz                    100%[======================================================================================================================================================>] 255.21M  34.9MB/s    in 6.7s    

2018-04-12 21:25:30 (38.2 MB/s) - '/opt/zimbra-install/zimbra-zcs-8.7.11.tar.gz' saved [267603851/267603851]

Extracting files from the archive
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/README.txt
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/addUser.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/globals.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/modules/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/modules/packages.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/modules/getconfig.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/modules/postinstall.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/util/utilfunc.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/readme_binary_en_US.txt
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/lib/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/lib/jars/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-store_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-mta_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-logger_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-apache_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-proxy_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-snmp_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-ldap_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-core_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-spell_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/packages/zimbra-dnscache_8.7.11.GA.1854.UBUNTU16.64_amd64.deb
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/zcl.txt
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/Migration_Exch_Admin.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/User Instructions for ZCS Import Wizard.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/zimbra_user_guide.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/Fedora Server Config.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/quick_start.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/Import_Wizard_Outlook.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/admin.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/MigrationWizard_Domino.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/MigrationWizard.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/RNZCSO_2005Beta.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/OSmultiserverinstall.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/docs/en_US/Zimbra iCalendar Migration Guide.pdf
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/data/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/data/versions-init.sql
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/install.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/bin/
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/bin/checkService.pl
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/bin/checkLicense.pl
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/bin/get_plat_tag.sh
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/bin/zmValidateLdap.pl
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/bin/zmdbintegrityreport
zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956/.BUILD_TYPE
Installing Zimbra Collaboration just the Software

Operations logged to /tmp/install.log.rJRbWY5R
Checking for existing installation...
    zimbra-chat...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-drive...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-suiteplus...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-ldap...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-logger...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-mta...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-dnscache...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-snmp...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-store...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-apache...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-spell...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-convertd...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-memcached...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-proxy...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-archiving...NOT FOUND
    zimbra-core...NOT FOUND


----------------------------------------------------------------------
PLEASE READ THIS AGREEMENT CAREFULLY BEFORE USING THE SOFTWARE.
SYNACOR, INC. ("SYNACOR") WILL ONLY LICENSE THIS SOFTWARE TO YOU IF YOU
FIRST ACCEPT THE TERMS OF THIS AGREEMENT. BY DOWNLOADING OR INSTALLING
THE SOFTWARE, OR USING THE PRODUCT, YOU ARE CONSENTING TO BE BOUND BY
THIS AGREEMENT. IF YOU DO NOT AGREE TO ALL OF THE TERMS OF THIS
AGREEMENT, THEN DO NOT DOWNLOAD, INSTALL OR USE THE PRODUCT.

License Terms for this Zimbra Collaboration Suite Software:
https://www.zimbra.com/license/zimbra-public-eula-2-6.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------



Do you agree with the terms of the software license agreement? [N] 




Use Zimbra's package repository [Y] 
Importing Zimbra GPG key

Configuring package repository
ERROR: Unable to install packages via apt-get
Please fix system to allow normal package installation before proceeding
Installing Zimbra Collaboration injecting the configuration
/opt/start.sh: line 140: /opt/zimbra/libexec/zmsetup.pl: No such file or directory
No passwd entry for user 'zimbra'
You can access now to your Zimbra Collaboration Server
```

But unfortunately, nothing is happening.
Any help in the right direction will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** Using [fly2matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856922/2691148)'s sollution I've managed to install docker. However it get stucks due to what I believe is on the DNS. Where the container starts with:

`* Restarting DNS forwarder and DHCP server configuration syntax check   [fail]`

Here is the [Full output log](https://pastebin.com/raw/imdMiyK5)

And the [zmsetup log](https://pastebin.com/raw/QN9fb66p)

Comment: Can you share you Dockerfile ?

Comment: I'm not using a docker file, I'm pulling `jorgedlcruz/zimbra` from the docker hub.

Comment: This tar.gz file is getting extracted to /opt/zimbra-install/zcs-8.7.11_GA_1854.UBUNTU16_64.20170531151956 and not in "/opt/zimbra-install/"

Answer (score 3):

It only needs few extra steps:

```
#>apt-get update
```

So do the following steps as you do not have your own Dockerfile: (With your Own Dockerfile it would have been clean and simple)

Create the container and start it (I have named this container as zim)

```
#>docker run -p 25:25 -p 80:80 -p 465:465 -p 587:587 -p 110:110 -p 143:143 -p 993:993 -p 995:995 -p 443:443 -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 -p 7071:7071 -p 9071:9071 -h zimbra-docker.zimbra.io --dns 127.0.0.1 --dns 8.8.8.8 -i -t -e PASSWORD=Zimbra2017 -d --name zim jorgedlcruz/zimbra
```

: Then open a console to the container

```
#>docker exec -it zim bash
root@zimbra-docker:~#apt-get update
```

Then stop the container using

```
#>docker stop zim
```

Then start the container using and see docker logs

```
#>docker start zim ; docker logs -f zim

Use Zimbra's package repository [Y]

Configuring package repository

Checking for installable packages

Found zimbra-core (local)
Found zimbra-ldap (local)
Found zimbra-logger (local)
Found zimbra-mta (local)
Found zimbra-dnscache (local)
Found zimbra-snmp (local)
Found zimbra-store (local)
Found zimbra-apache (local)
Found zimbra-spell (local)
Found zimbra-memcached (repo)
Found zimbra-proxy (local)
Found zimbra-chat (repo)

Select the packages to install

Install zimbra-ldap [Y]
Install zimbra-logger [Y]
Install zimbra-mta [Y]
Install zimbra-dnscache [Y]
Install zimbra-snmp [Y]
Install zimbra-store [Y]
Install zimbra-apache [Y]
Install zimbra-spell [Y]
Install zimbra-memcached [Y]
Install zimbra-proxy [Y]
Install zimbra-chat [Y]
Install zimbra-drive [Y] Checking required space for zimbra-core
Checking space for zimbra-store
/opt/zimbra requires at least 5GB of space to install.
```

Comment: I've posted an update to my initial question, thank you so far for your contribution!